# Spectral norms of Wishart matrices

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, random-matrices

For IID $x$ drawn from $\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$, is the following true?

$$\mathbb E \left[ \left\|\frac 1b \sum_{i=1}^b x_ix_i^T\right\|_2\right ]\le \frac{b+1}{b}\|\Sigma\|+\frac{1}{b}\operatorname{Tr}\Sigma$$

Simulations [suggest](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/stats.SE-wishart-spectral-norm.nb) it's true.

[image]

Formula comes by extrapolating from analogous [result](https://mathoverflow.net/a/436131/7655) for expected Frobenius norm
$$\mathbb E \left[ \left\|\frac 1b \sum_{i=1}^b x_ix_i^T\right\|_F^2\right ]=\frac{(b+1)}{b}\operatorname{Tr}\Sigma^2+\frac{1}{b} (\operatorname{Tr} \Sigma)^2$$